# How many workspaces should be taken - Poisson?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The following scenario:

Customers come to the center and get in touch with the information and wait until they are called from the waiting area. (As with the doctor, for example)

- Customers should not wait more than 10 minutes. This maximum waiting time varies from day to day. This means that more waiting time can be calculated on Monday than on Friday, for example. Always 100% of the customers are processed.
- We know when the customers arrive and how long the average processing time is.
- There is a workstation limitation: that is, if only 6 workstations are available, only 6 workstation can be occupied to the maximum. If only 6 workstations are available, only these 6 can be scheduled at maximum. This number is also variable.

**So the goal is**: how many workstations should be occupied (per interval) so that the maximum waiting time for a customer is met.

The following information is available to us per interval (15 minutes):

- Max. workspaces per interval
- Customer volume and average processing time per interval

Extra Info:
For each interval, there is a value for the processing time and a value for the customer volume. These are not constant but simply average values. If we assume that we have 24 hours open, we have 96 intervals per day. For each of these 96 intervals, as indicated above, we have a numeric value for the average processing time and a numerical value for the (expected) customer volume.
The interval time is fixed at 15 mins. The average processing time can be both. more or less than 15 Min.

How do you calculate this best? Does a Poisson distribution make sense here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Customers should not wait more than 10 minutes. This maximum waiting time varies from day to day." This is a strange set up. You're trying to make sure that there's a worst case scenario for wait time, but that worst case scenario depends on the day of the week? Why? Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Also by itself "should not wait more than 10 minutes" is meaningless. You need to specify "X% of customers will wait 10 minutes or less". Since you said that average processing time might be more than 15 minutes and since you're modelling this with random variables, it's just a matter of time until a lot of people arrive at the same time and people will be waiting more than 10 minutes. What you have to target is how often this might happen.

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what it is that you have exactly. You said that "The following information is available to us per interval (...) Customer volume and average processing time per interval". So you're assuming that you know customer volume for all time into the future? No need to use random variables then, just make a simulation and check whether the wait time in your simulation never goes over 10 minutes. Or do you mean that you know average customer arrival rate per time period in the future?

Comment: This said, this seems like the kind of problem that has been completely solved somewhere in specialist technical books, no?

Comment: @oneloop  Where do I find such a book where it says how to solve this? And yes, I mean that we know the average rate of arrival of customers.

Comment: I don't know about a book, but the name of the field is [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). Maybe check the references on wikipedia.

Comment: @oneloop thanks. Do you mean you could calculate this with poisson or an erlang calculation?

Comment: I mean, depends on what the circumstances are. If I absolutely must come up with something, I'll write some code that models the customers and generates random numbers for simulating the customers arriving (yes, with Poisson), and run it a few million times and measure what the distributions are of the things I want to measure.

Comment: @oneloop thank you for your help. I thought the whole thing could somehow mathematically break down by rebuilding the poisson formula

Comment: I don't know. Compare with physics. Yes, force equals mass times acceleration, but as you propose adding extra slopes and levers and pulleys the thing gets more and more complicated to model. I think that's what your multiple requirements do. We can still have some intuition for what will happen though.

Comment: Consider an equilibrium where you service customers at the same rate as they arrive. Then consider perturbations around this: if the rate at which they arrive is higher, you will eventually fill up, otherwise the thing will eventually become empty. Now consider that the arrivals don't necessary match the arrival rate, but have some fluctuations around the expected value, given an equilibrium, or given a certain arrival-service differencial, what is the probability that at a certain interval you fill up. But much more than this you better just code it and simulate it, I think.

Comment: Read those books and come back to answer the question ;-) Or hope that someone smarter answers it :D

Comment: Last comment, look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73433/approach-to-a-poisson-question?rq=1) question. There's no answer there, but pay attention to the formulation of the problem and of the question. That is something that I can believe has a simple formula for answer. Also notice how they formulate the constraint. They don't say "service time can't exceed $t$", instead they say "what is the probability that service time will exceed $t$?"

Comment: Thanks!. I'm reading in there right now. I have the following variables: Average processing time / interval. Average volume / interval. and maximum waiting time of 10 minutes. As a result, I need something like: use workstations / interval. @oneloop